# Scripted field regex not working on multiple node

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I would like to create a scripted field based on cs_uri_query column. I was using elasticsearch 7.5 until 7.6 when i created this regex formula. It was working fine in scripted field on index A. Now i've upgraded my elasticsearch into 7.7 and i've ingested index B to my elasticsearch. Index B and Index A have the same format (same everything in columns) so i would like to use the same regex formula. But unfortunately when i copy my index A scripted field into index B.

### it returning this error on index B

```
{
 "root_cause": [
  {
   "type": "script_exception",
   "reason": "compile error",
   "script_stack": [
    "... = 0) return '';\r\ndef m = /(...(?=&custid))/.matche ...",
    "                             ^---- HERE"
   ],
   "script": "if (doc['cs_uri_query.keyword'].size() == 0) return '';\r\ndef m = /(...(?=&custid))/.matcher(doc['cs_uri_query.keyword'].value);\r\nif(m.find () )\r\n{return m.group(1) } \r\nelse { return \"No ID\" }",
   "lang": "painless",
   "position": {
    "offset": 65,
    "start": 40,
    "end": 90
   }
  }
 ],
 "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
 "reason": "all shards failed",
 "phase": "query",
 "grouped": true,
 "failed_shards": [
  {
   "shard": 0,
   "index": "janmei",
   "node": "KVuYPKPBRIO-mIQu0lS3LQ",
   "reason": {
    "type": "script_exception",
    "reason": "compile error",
    "script_stack": [
     "... = 0) return '';\r\ndef m = /(...(?=&custid))/.matche ...",
     "                             ^---- HERE"
    ],
    "script": "if (doc['cs_uri_query.keyword'].size() == 0) return '';\r\ndef m = /(...(?=&custid))/.matcher(doc['cs_uri_query.keyword'].value);\r\nif(m.find () )\r\n{return m.group(1) } \r\nelse { return \"No ID\" }",
    "lang": "painless",
    "position": {
     "offset": 65,
     "start": 40,
     "end": 90
    },
    "caused_by": {
     "type": "illegal_state_exception",
     "reason": "Regexes are disabled. Set [script.painless.regex.enabled] to [true] in elasticsearch.yaml to allow them. Be careful though, regexes break out of Painless's protection against deep recursion and long loops."
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

### sample

```
id=000&custid=77777777&email=email@gmail.com
```

### scripted field

```
if (doc['cs_uri_query.keyword'].size() == 0) return '';
def m = /(...(?=&custid))/.matcher(doc['cs_uri_query.keyword'].value);
if(m.find () )
{return m.group(1) } 
else { return "No ID" }
```

i was copy the exact same script from index A to index B. Can someone explain this to me? Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states,

> Regexes are disabled. Set [script.painless.regex.enabled] to [true] in elasticsearch.yaml to allow them. Be careful though, regexes break out of Painless's protection against deep recursion and long loops.

You need to set

```
script.painless.regex.enabled: true
```

in your `elasticsearch.yml` fiel and restart ES.

Comment: Hi Mr Val, Thank you so much again. I dont know how to thank you. I created index A while just having single node. Now i have 2 node and i didnt set script.painless.regex.enabled: true on the latest node. Thank you so much for your help. It really helps me everytime. Thank you so much Mr Val. It works really well now!!!

Comment: does this " script.painless.regex.enabled: true" have to added on only data node/ master node or every node that bound to master node? Thank you